# Alternative exercise for Hang Clean (torn meniscus)

Tags: lifting

I have a torn meniscus and I am looking for an alternative to Hang Cleans.

[image: Hang Cleans]

The doctor has told me that I can do any exercise as long as:

- I am sure my knee does not bent up to 90º or more
- This eliminates deep squats and hang cleans.

Is there an alternative that uses as many muscles as hang cleans?

At this moment I am doing Dead lifts as shown in image but I am not sure it uses as many muscles as Hang Cleans

[image: Dead Lift]

Answer (score 2):

The power variations (power cleans and power snatches) involve landing in the power position (with your legs above 90 deg), like a half or quater squat.

That said however I am not a medical professional but I would avoid the O-lifts in general. You usually land up putting yourself in dangerous situations during the learning process. I would stick to deadlifts and barbell rows. They're both very good compound exercises which sound a bit safer for you condition.

Consult your doctor and please be careful with the deadlifts as well. It is a good exercise but can be dangerous if carried out with bad form.

Comment: I assumed OP is familiar with the hanging clean, but it is just that: an assumption. Maybe OP can clarify.